# quicksort not sorting c++

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to write a quicksort function to sort anywhere between 10 and 1,000,000 numbers. It iterates through everything but does not sort, just prints the vector as is.

For some reason it jumps out of the `while` loop way too soon.
The test input I'm using is: (3 6 2 5 1 7 9 10 4 8). 
And it's output: (1 2 6 5 3 7 9 10 4 8)

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Which file would you like to sort?\n";
    std::cin >> file;

    std::ifstream in(file.c_str());

    // Read all the ints from in:
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(in), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
            std::back_inserter(numbers));

    int max = numbers.size();
    quickSort(numbers, 0, max-1);

    // Print the vector with tab separators:
    std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


void quickSort(vector<int> &numbers, int start, int end)
{
    int i = start;
    int j = end;
    int pivot=numbers[start];
    int temp;
    while( i != j )
    {
        while( numbers[i] < pivot && i < j)
            i++;
        while( numbers[j] >= pivot && i < j)
            j--;

        temp = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = numbers[j];
        numbers[j] = temp;

        if( j < start )
        {
            quickSort( numbers, start, j );
        }

        if( i < start )
        {
            quickSort( numbers, i, end);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: When you step through the program in a debugger, at what point does the actual state of the program deviate from what you expect the state to be?

Comment: once it gets to `temp = numbers[i];` it sets it to '7' and I don't quite understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly among other things, you aren't actually looking at the contents of the vector when you move your indices to find a swap.  This section:

```
    while( i < pivot && i < j)
        i++;
    while( j >= pivot && i < j)
        j--;
```

should be changed to this:

```
    while( numbers[i] < pivot && i < j)
        i++;
    while( numbers[j] >= pivot && i < j)
        j--;
```

As one of the commenters mentioned, the bigger lesson is to learn to use a good debugger to step through your code.

Similarly, you should be selecting pivot as an array value.  E.g. `pivot = numbers[start]`

Comment: It atleast sorts a couple numbers now. But now I can't figure out why its not sorting them all. I updated my question with the input and output, as well as my updated code.

Comment: Even with the fixes, I think you still have a few problems.  I can't recommend enough learning to use gdb or some other debugger.  In particular, I think that the two recursive calls to quicksort should be outside of the while loop - you first want to do all of the swaps, and then recurse on the two halves of the list.  Second, I don't understand why you have the `if (j < start)` before recursing.  I suspect that you might want a different condition there.

Answer (score 3):

This line looks out of place:

```
int pivot=numbers.size()/2;
```

You're picking for your pivot the middle element of the `numbers` vector regardless of the `start` and `end` positions.

Comment: Yep, should be 'int pivot = numbers[(start + end) / 2];'

Comment: For my purpose, I believe making the middle element be the pivot makes the most sense. If I were to replace what I have with `pivot = numbers[(start + end)/2];` it would set the pivot to be the middle element anyway with my code.

Comment: @Fourthmeal70 No the regular pivot is end-1 for the regular quicksort.